# How to apply custom object detector on pre-captured video?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tf.keras, object-detection-api

Based on what is written on the TensorFlow web page about object-detection API, I have trained a custom model, and its checkpoint is obtained successfully, now I am going to apply this trained model on a pre-captured video(not webcam frames).
Now, I would like to know how can I do this? is there any pre-written code that can help me in this way?
thanks for your comments.
best wishes to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use most of the code from the docs [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/object_detection_camera.html?highlight=video).

The only minor change you need to make [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/object_detection_camera.html?highlight=video#define-the-video-stream) is, instead of `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, use `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video_file)` and it should work

Comment: thanks a lot I find your comment very helpful.